# Changing HISTSIZE in ubuntu 16.0.4LTS

Tags: bash, command-history

I've been trying to change the HISTSIZE system wide and it hasn't been working. I've tried multiple different methods :

1. adding  `/etc/profile` export HISTSIZE=100
2. adding `/etc/enviroment` HISTSIZE=100
3. adding `/etc/bash.bashrc` HISTSIZE=100

I don't want to change the per-user `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Did you logout /login again?

Comment: or alternatively run `source /etc/profile` or whatever file you change

Comment: How do you log into this machine? Have you added that line to _all_ of those files or do you remove it from one and then add it to the other? Are you sure your user(s) doesn't have a different setting? Anything in the per-user file will overwrite the globals.

Comment: I assume /etc/enviroment is a typo for /etc/environment?

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; See where HISTSIZE is changed:

`grep HISTSIZE /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login`

---

The HISTSIZE is just an environment variable and environment variables are set or overwritten in a few places. I will assume you are using bash (I'm sure other shells also use HISTSIZE, but bash is often the default shell)

The default HISTSIZE is 500 as you can see in the bash/bind.c: https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/d233b485e83c3a784b803fb894280773f16f2deb/lib/readline/bind.c#L2040

When a user logs in, a pretty complex tree of config files is loaded. Here is an excellent post about this: https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html

And here is the relevant diagram from that post:
[image]

Now, when running a normal, interactive, remote (purple line) shell you can see the following files are parsed:

- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bash_login

Any of these files can set or change the HISTSIZE variable.

Now you can read the current HISTSIZE variable by typing:`echo $HISTSIZE`

If the result is an empty line, it was not set and the default 500 should apply.

Any other amount will have been set by other scripts in the list above. You can have a quick look by grepping for HISTSIZE like this:
`grep HISTSIZE /etc/profile /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login`

Comment: That diagram... It serves the purpose of showing that "it's complex", but to try to decipher it is not really useful, especially since it differs between Unix systems (and the system for which the diagram was created is not mentioned). Note that `bash` on two different systems also may differ in the way it's invoking some startup files.  The real reference is the system's own `bash(1)` manual.