# history command does not show all lines in HISTFILE

Tags: bash, command-history

When I use this command `cat -n $(echo $HISTFILE) | grep -v "#"` I get 4000+ lines. (the grep omits the timestamp added to the histfile)

```
1 pwd
...
2017 cd ~
...
4033 git push
```

But when I use this command `history` I get only 2000+ lines.

```
1 18/09/19 11:00:38 cd ~
...
2017 30/10/19 09:41:50 git push
```

**Why does my history command omit half of the lines?**

I suspect that the timestamp in `$HISTFILE` is the culprit, but how to circumvent that behaviour? Or is the suspicion wrong?

I have modified my `env` variables used by the `history` command as follows:

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

I have done these modifications, because I want to have an infinte history and an additional timestamp. I would like to keep these and make the history command output all of the lines of the `HISTFILE`.

I am using the **OS** `cat /etc/*release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize

Comment: However, even if user adjusted HISTSIZE to be eg. 10000, there would still be less lines returned than printing the history file, as it is not the size of the history buffer that is the limitation, but rather the fact that the file stores all bash sessions, while the history command being run is only in the current bash session. Hence my answer below.

Comment: Note: `cat -n $(echo $HISTFILE)` is bizarre and flawed. `cat -n "$HISTFILE"` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

The history command lists the history of the current bash session only, whereas the file contains the history of all bash sessions. As such running history in a session may well show fewer results than the file. Also, history is meant for looking up "recent" commands, and is thus limited in length according to $HISTSIZE (to increase HISTSIZE in your environment, see [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493173/changing-histsize-in-ubuntu-16-0-4lts)).

To update the history in a particular session to include all the latest commands from the history file, run history with -r or -n. From the man page:

-n : Read  the  history  lines  not  already read from the history file into the current history list.  These are lines appended to the history file since the beginning of the current bash session.

-r : Read the contents of the history file and append them to the current history list.):

```
user@machine:~> history
994  ssh server
995  history --help
996  man history
997  history
```

Only 997 lines returned...

```
user@machine:~> history -r
```

Refresh...

```
user@machine:~> history

994  ssh server
995  history --help
996  man history
997  history
998  history -r
999  ping 10.10.10.10
1000  ping 10.10.10.1
...
1992  ssh server02
1993  history
```

Now lists 1993 commands. So includes history added by any other terminals that you had open and used, which will give you similar output (tailed to $HISTSIZE lines) to reading the raw file (limited by $HISTFILESIZE). Beware of subtle differences... -n read current bash session lines, -r reads the whole file.

Comment: nice, but that was not the question.

Comment: I'll edit to explain, thanks for pointing out... I inferred that was the case from the output of history before and then after the -r. But I'll be more explicit.

Comment: That does print 1000 lines. Not what i wanted.

Comment: @kiltek: absolutely, that's the default value of HISTSIZE - echo $HISTSIZE = 1000 in most distro's. In that case check out the link from pLumo, and also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493173/changing-histsize-in-ubuntu-16-0-4lts. It applies to most cases... and shows you where to change the default environment value.